# Get all sections for appname in RegEdit

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, settings, regedit

Regarding the `GetSetting()` function in .NET, i have found the `GetAllSettings()`. That is, `GetAllSettings("MyApp", "MySection")` will give me all keys under "MySection". I can't, how ever, find anything for getting all sections for my App. In the case above, i would like to get "MySection" as an result for searching "MyApp".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (C#):

```
var regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MyApp",
                    RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree));
var sections = regKey.GetSubKeyNames();
```

I'm not sure about VB but you may have to use `Registry.CurrentUser` instead of `LocalMachine` and then modify the path accordingly (`SOFTWARE\MyApp` is the path here), based on where your keys are. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here's the corresponding code for VB.Net - taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim rkTest As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("RegistryOpenSubKeyExample")
Console.WriteLine("There are {0} subkeys under Test9999.", _
    rkTest.SubKeyCount.ToString())
For Each subKeyName As String In rkTest.GetSubKeyNames()
    Dim tempKey As RegistryKey = _
        rkTest.OpenSubKey(subKeyName)
    Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "There are {0} values for " & _
        "{1}.", tempKey.ValueCount.ToString(), tempKey.Name)
    For Each valueName As String In tempKey.GetValueNames()
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-8}: {1}", valueName, _
            tempKey.GetValue(valueName).ToString())
    Next 
Next
```

This code should work, just make sure your path etc. is being set properly. Or if you can post a screenshot of your registry hives, I can guide you better.

Comment: Dim regKey as RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine/CurrentUser.OpenSubkey(...  is Nothing after run and it breaks on GetSubkeyNames() since it's not an instance of an object.

Comment: Do you need the answer in VB only? You should drop the C# tag then. Regarding your other issue, I'd check the corresponding code example on MSDN for VB.Net.

Comment: No no sorry, VB is not necessary. But i'm using it ant that's why i pasted it. :)

Comment: OK. I pasted VB code for reference anyway. See my updated answer.